# PL buildiers version is implemented at two places in Xcode. How to set it right?

Tags: xcode, simulator

While writing an app in Xcode8 (swift3) for adding pictures with titles I set up two view controllers, the first of which was embedded in navigation controller.  I’ve added an “Add” barbutton in the navigation control of the first view controller (VC), tapping which, the second view controller is shown.  I receive the following error when I tap on the “Add” button on the 1st VC.

"objc[692]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x155d38cc0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x154b876f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."

Can somebody please help me understand the issue and to solve it.

Comment: please format your post properly

Comment: Also, read how to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)